# Can video recording on an Android smartphone be paused?

Tags: video-recording

I've got an HTC Wildfire with Android Froyo 2.2.
When I record videos with it, I want to be able to pause the recording, in order to pick up recording at the exact place where I paused.

This is not supported by the built in video recorder. Is this common for Android phones, or are there phones out there that support pause in video recording?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like this is either specific to the hardware of the camera or even the software the manufacture using on the device.

I have a samsung galaxy s (Vibrant) and I can pause and resume video recording. My previous device, the HTC Dream (ADP1/G1) could also pause and resume (from what i can remember).